# Is it a known bug that PHP-Redis in PHP 5.6 crashes if setting a key value to NULL?

Tags: php, crash, redis, php-5.6

This PHP code crashes the host (Apache) with a segfault:

```
$myRedis->hSet("some key name", NULL);
```

This is troubling to me, because PHP is supposed to be a high-level language that doesn't dereference NULL pointers, but instead either accepts them as "empty value" or throws an exception.

Am I the only one seeing this? (This code worked fine in PHP 5.3 and 5.5)

Comment: SO isn't the place to ask this. Why not [open an issue](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues) with the project so they can look and advise you?

Comment: segfault in which module? have you debugged this?

Comment: Segfault in the PHP Redis module. And, yes, it was known -- PHP Redis on HEAD has a fix. You have to check it out and build it yourself to get the fix.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$myRedis->hSet("some key name", null, null);
```

Further, 
[Check This](http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-redis-in-php-using-predis/)